# Firestore to Produce a Snapshot When the Where Condition Changes

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wanted to make the snapshot to be updated every time when the where condition updates.
So the condition is just like when the favItemsID data is updated, it will trigger the snapshot to refresh.
Is there any approach where I can achieve the results to be dynamically updated when the condition in the query changes? Currently my Firestore Data Structure is just as below:

User

- name `<String>`
- favItemsID `List<String>`

Item

- itemID `<String>`
- itemTitle `<String>`
- itemDescription `<String>`

Here is my attempt of code

```
static Stream<QuerySnapshot<Item>> favItem(userID) {
    var favItems = <String>[];
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('User')
        .withConverter(
          fromFirestore: User.fromFirestore,
          toFirestore: (user, options) => user.toFirestore(),
        )
        .doc(userID)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((snapshot) {
      favItems = snapshot.data()!.favItemsID;
    });

    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Item')
        .withConverter(
          fromFirestore: Item.fromFirestore,
          toFirestore: (item, options) => item.toFirestore(),
        )
        .where('itemID', whereIn: favItems)
        .snapshots();
  }
```

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Going forward, please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the `.listen()` method returns a `StreamSubscription`, not a `Stream`, so it cannot be used as the return value of the `favItem` function.

It looks like you want to transform the Stream of `User` into a Stream of `QuerySnapshots` of Items.

There are 2 ways to achieve this:

- You can use `switchMap` on the `.snapshots()` method. switchMap is a common operator in the `dart:async` library that is available in Flutter and other Dart applications.

```
static Stream<QuerySnapshot<Item>> favItem(userID) {
  return FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('User')
      .withConverter(
        fromFirestore: User.fromFirestore,
        toFirestore: (user, options) => user.toFirestore(),
      )
      .doc(userID)
      .snapshots()
      .map((snapshot) => snapshot.data()!.favItemsID)
      .switchMap((favItems) => FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Item')
          .withConverter(
            fromFirestore: Item.fromFirestore,
            toFirestore: (item, options) => item.toFirestore(),
          )
          .where('itemID', whereIn: favItems)
          .snapshots());
}
```

- Use a regular map operator to map all User into the required model:

```
static Stream<QuerySnapshot<Item>> favItem(userID) {
  return FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('User')
      .withConverter(
        fromFirestore: User.fromFirestore,
        toFirestore: (user, options) => user.toFirestore(),
      )
      .doc(userID)
      .snapshots()
      .map((userSnapshot) {
        List<String> favItems = userSnapshot.data()!.favItemsID;
        return FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('Item')
            .withConverter(
              fromFirestore: Item.fromFirestore,
              toFirestore: (item, options) => item.toFirestore(),
            )
            .where('itemID', whereIn: favItems)
            .snapshots();
      })
      .flatten();
}
```

With the `flatten` operator, the `favItem` function will return a single stream of QuerySnapshots that combines the updates from all the inner streams created by the map operator. Although you can remove it If you want to return the value of the map operator as a `Stream` of `Streams`.

Although there are other ways to achieve this transformation for more about this go through this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72303214/20239914)